# Performing a weighted distance between matrix rows with matrix operators in R

Tags: r, matrix

I thought I was able to do the following computation myself using R matrices, but I was wrong. Based on a larger version of the matrix below, I would like to calculate the following formula

[image: formula]

The result are simply squared differences among the rows of the matrix divided by the variance of the columns, all eventually divided by 9, which is the nr of matrix columns. The result of this calculation would be a square matrix of weighted disances among the matrix rows.

```
structure(c(4.36, 4.44, 4.04, 4.49, 4.09, 4.46, 3.81, 4.44, 3.4, 
3.09, 3.31, 3.7, 4.28, 4.62, 4.2, 4.05, 4.28, 3.72, 3.66, 4.49, 
4.17, 4.85, 5.18, 4.26, 4.29, 4.3, 3.83, 4.38, 4.74, 4.95, 5.33, 
4.82, 4.39, 5.16, 3.6, 4.58), .Dim = c(4L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Australia", "Austria", "Brazil", "Canada"), c("Performance.Orientation", 
    "Future.Orientation", "Gender.Egalitarianism", "Assertiveness", 
    "Humane.orientation", "in.group.collectivism", "institutional.collectivism", 
    "power.concentration.decentralization..power.distance.", 
    "uncertainty.avoidance")))
```

I really appreciate any help I can get because I wouldn't know how to solve this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @DavidArenburg thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately, neither seems to work. The first one give back a one-line solution, while the second, for some reason, gives back a 35x9 data table. The ideal result of this function is a 4x4 square matrix with the names of the countries on both dimensions.

Comment: I dunno how to break it to you, but your formula there returns a scalar value for each `j` value.  You're not goint to get a square matrix unless you hack the output.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Exactly. The distance between line j and another line is a scalar. So the distance between j and all matrix rows (including j itself) is a vector equal to the number of rows. But the distance between any row and any other row is a matrix. Isn't it? This explanation of the problem was the best I could give. If you can suggest something more precise, I would be very happy if you could share it. Many thanks.

Comment: I'll go with mrip's answer.  I see what you want now; it's a matter of collecting all the `i,j` outputs into a matrix.

Comment: Hi Carl, exactly. I wanted to write that formula using matrix notation - in that case, it would have been clearer - but I didn't know how to do that consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dist` function here.  First divide each column by its standard deviation to do the scaling you want.

```
mat2<-apply(mat,2,function(x)x/sd(x))
x<-dist(mat2)^2/9
x
#            Australia      Austria       Brazil
# Austria 1.2201838730                          
# Brazil  2.2438097238 2.6753385616             
# Canada  0.5118006068 1.9591707783 3.3896964564
```

To recover an ordinary matrix:

```
as.matrix(x)
#              Australia     Austria      Brazil       Canada
# Australia 0.0000000000 1.220183873 2.243809724 0.5118006068
# Austria   1.2201838730 0.000000000 2.675338562 1.9591707783
# Brazil    2.2438097238 2.675338562 0.000000000 3.3896964564
# Canada    0.5118006068 1.959170778 3.389696456 0.0000000000
```